# how to convert python pyinstaller distribution directory to Debian package

Tags: python-3.x, linux, debian, pyinstaller

how to convert python pyinstaller distribution directory to Debian package?
I executed this code generating python build

`pyinstaller --add-data "framework/*.ttf:framework" --add-data "ui/resources/*.png:ui/resources" --add-data "ui/resources/*.gif:ui/resources" --noconsole --icon "ui/resources/test.ico" --name "package_ename" app.py`

after execute the above snippet generated `build and dist directory`.
dist directory contain the executable file.
I need to convert that dist folder to debian package.
is it possible?

I tried to many resources. could't found any result.
please help me

Comment: please give some more details.

Comment: I  was generated dist directory  through  pyinstaller. dist directory contain executable things. need to convert to debian package

Comment: Just create a Debian package. The good of packages is that they are not automatically generated, but people give inputs (dependencies, descriptions, etc.), and also they fix and control how program works, so to fit in a system. And "executable file" in a Debian Package is usually just the python files. [In other words: debian packages and pyinstaller are different tools to do different stuffs: it is much easier if you do the two things separately (and for different OS)